# Rails 4 - Access attributes of nested model in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have ***Account*** model which have a `has_many` relationship with ***User*** model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :account
```

I added ***avatar*** attribute to ***User*** model using paperclip.

I want each user to have access to the common account settings, and inside it having the possibility to upload his/her own avatar.

I use simple_form so I tried this:

```
<%= simple_form_for current_account, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%# here come account settings %>
    <%= f.input :time_zone, :label => t(".timezone"), 
                 :
                 :

    <%# here I need to access current user attributes %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :user, current_account.users.first do |user_form| %>
        <%= user_form.file_field :avatar, :error => false %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**First problem:**
I need some logic to access current_user instead of `current_account.users.first`. Since there is a superadmin which can access all accounts, use `current_user` is not enough.

**Second (and bigger) problem:**
I added in my controller the avatar parameter to the whitelist:

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:time_zone, :logo, :description, user: [:avatar])
end
```

When I try to update my model:

```
if current_account.update(allowed_params)
```

I get this error:

```
unknown attribute: user
```

I also tried:

```
params.require(:account).permit(:language, :time_zone, :logo, :description, :user_attributes => [:avatar])
```

and:

```
params.require(:account).permit(:language, :time_zone, :logo, :description, :users_attributes => [:avatar])
```

(in plural)

but since I use `ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise` I get:

```
found unpermitted parameters: user
```

It must be something very easy, some help please?

Comment: Can you post the params which you're sending? This will help us better help with Q2

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZBt4w/DSAVm8u73n+NNfnDJ9SQ/sYpbEd5UUkXaOdYc=", "account"=>{"language"=>"es", "time_zone"=>"UTC", "description"=>"", "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003560d80 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140514-4653-woicz0>, @original_filename="john-doe.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"account[user][avatar]\"; filename=\"john-doe.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Guardar"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it!!

The problem is the one-to-many relationship and the way I tried to access a single instance of user. The correct way to do it is:

```
<% current_account.users.each_with_index do |user, index|%>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :users, user do |user_form| %>
        <%= user_form.file_field :avatar, :error => false %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the iteration should be done over the relation, and only when having a 
single instance "in hand" we can user the `simple_fields_for`.

Also, notice that the first parameter passed to `simple_fields_for` is `:users` and not `:user`, since this is a one-to-many relationship.